# Quantum Physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data
   A beam of ultraviolet light with wavelength of 200 nm is incident on a metal whose work function is 3.0 eV. Note that this metal is applied with +1.0 V with respect to the ground. Determine the largest kinetic energy of the photoelectrons generated in this process.

I am not entirely sure what the statement about the +1.0 V implies and hence I simply used the formula 
Kmax = hf - phi . Substituting the appropriate values gives Kmax = 5.139*10^-19 J . Am I on the correct path ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: http://se.u.94y.info may help